# How to make a countdown timer for 5 second countdown?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game where there is a 5 seconds countdown, I am doing this countdown on the server side. I want the timer to start over and over again when I send it the request it will respond with the current timer value. For example if 2.2 seconds has passed when the request is made it sends 2.8 seconds as a response and so on. Below you can see my code at the moment, thanks in advance!

```js
router.get("/:result", (req,res) =>{

const result = JSON.parse(req.params.result)
var timerTime = {
    time: null
}

if(result.message == "startNewTime"){
    //Start the timer

}else if(result.message == "checkingTime"){

//Get the timer value and set it to be the timerTime.time value
//Start the timer from 5 seconds again

res.send(JSON.stringify(timerTime))

}

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. The problem I had with the date.now() method was that I was sending a new request and the variable value reset ofc so I just saved it to the session and got it working. Thanks bye!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setTimeout() ?
You can pass the function or result as first argument and milliseconds as second parameter.

Then you can approach it differently! Try setting a simple counter.

```
let counter = 0
for(let i = 0; i < 5; I++){
setTimeout(counter++, 1000)
}
```

Maybe it works this way? You can only track seconds this way though, not milliseconds.

Comment: Yes I have the and I know I need to use it, but the problem is that I don't know how to format the code and get the time that is left. I have tried Date.now() and substract with the current Date.now() but I could not get it working. Thanks for the answer tho. @Detoqx

Comment: Then you can approach it differently! Try setting a simple counter.